# Prevent timer from restart on reload

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prevent my timer from restarting after reloading the page, but i cant seem to know how to do it. I have also come across localstorage.

I cant seem to understand how i can put it in though i have tried.

```
<script type="">

    var upgradeTime = 50;
var seconds = upgradeTime;
function timer() {
  var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
  var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
  var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
  var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
  var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
  }
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = pad(days) + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = alert('done');
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
</script>
```

It doesnt save at all in the ones i have tried at worse the timer stops entirely.

Comment: Have you tried to use [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but never pass a string to `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`), pass the function directly: `setInterval(timer, 1000);`. (Passing as a string will break linting, minification, and possibly other things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to store the remaining time independent from the page reload, localStorage or sessionStorage (or cookies, already mentioned) are a good way for this.

Using your code you need to initially check, whether the second value is already stored in your localStorage like this:

```
var seconds = localStorage.getItem("remainingSeconds") || upgradeTime;
```

This code checks, if you have stored a key named "remainingSeconds" in your localStorage and if not, it uses the default value from upgradeTime.

When you decrement your seconds, you also must update the new value in your localStorage like this:

```
seconds--;
localStorage.setItem("remainingSeconds", seconds);
```

Just read a little about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to understand it, it is a really simple way to store data persistent. If you only want it bound to a user's session, use sessionStorage instead.

Side note:

In your line:

```
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = alert('done');
```

you are trying to add javascript code to the innerHTML. That will not work.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me but can i use that alert button to disable another button

Answer (score 0):

Javascript isn't really implicitly ideal for this. Seeing as the script is loaded each time the page is loaded, the state is reset each time. You could try saving the state to a cookie with the `window.onbeforeunload`event and then pull the state from cookie each time the page is loaded. That would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use `localStorage`. Also, it is better to not set a target number of seconds (relative), but to set a target *time* (absolute). That way you avoid that any latency plays a role in the displayed count down.

It makes no sense to assign `alert("done")` to a DOM element's value. Just assign "done", and better assign to `textContent`, since you assign text, not HTML.

Don't pass a string to `setInterval`; it is bad practice, since the string needs to be parsed. Just pass the function object. I prefer using `setTimeout` and call it each time when needed: that way you don't need a global variable to maintain the value returned by `setInterval`.

I have added a `<button id="start">start</button>` button in the HTML part, which will be hidden during the time that the count down is active, but will appear when the count down is over.

Here is how it could work:

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<button id="start">Start count down</button>
```

JS:

```
var countDown = document.getElementById('countdown');
var startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
// Link the start of the timer with a button click
startBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    upgradeTime = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) + 50;  // set count down to 50 secs from now
    localStorage.setItem('upgradeTime', upgradeTime); // ...and save it.
    timer(); // Call timer function immediately
});
var upgradeTime = +localStorage.getItem('upgradeTime');
if (upgradeTime) timer(); // continue the current count down

function timer() {
    startBtn.style.display = "none"; // hide start-button
    // Calculate the actual number of seconds remaining from now:
    var seconds     = upgradeTime - Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = seconds - days*86400;
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = hoursLeft - hours*3600;
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

    function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
    }
    countDown.textContent = pad(days) + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
    if (seconds <= 0) { // Deal with negative as well...
        localStorage.removeItem('upgradeTime'); // remove the storage
        countDown.textContent = 'done'; // Don't assign alert() here
        startBtn.style.display = ""; // show the start-button
    } else { 
        // with setTimeout you don't need to maintain the return value
        setTimeout(timer, 1000); // don't pass a string; it's bad practice
    }
}
```

See it run on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvja09k1/1/).

Comment: After the timer is done and you refresh its starts again. i want to use that alert to disable a button after timeout

Comment: Did you read my answer, and the last paragraph? There is no mention of a button in your question, so I could not know about it. BTW: an `alert` does not disable a button; once you click OK on the popup, the button will still be there to click on. If you would add information (HTML, ...click handler...) in your question, I could integrate that in my answer.

Comment: Also, if you don't want the countdown to ever start again, you will *never* be able to use that page again. Could you explain the logic with which you want to *start* a new countdown?

Comment: I want to use another button to restart the timer in case its done and i want to reuse the same variable, thats the logic of the alert

Comment: I am not sure which button you refer to. Maybe you mean the "OK" button that is on the alert popup? Anyway, I would not use `alert` for this at all. I updated my answer with an HTML-button that will appear when there is no active count down. Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: thanks for everything so far but actually i would want to stop it not start, thanks for that too

Comment: What do you mean with "stop"? I don't see that aspect in your original question. Do you want to interrupt an ongoing count-down with a separate button? Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zLfmbgne/